# Кириллица заменяется на вопросы MySql, php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Вопрос возможно повторный (и не второй), но перепробовал всё что можно, но в таблицу всё равно заносятся вопросы, вместо русских букв.
Вот, как подключаюсь к базе.

```
$db->query("set character_set_client='utf8'");
//$db - \mysqli
$db->query("set character_set_results='utf8'");
$db->query("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
$db->query("set names 'utf8'");
$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

У базы и самой таблицы установлены сравнения - utf8_general_ci.
Сам файл, где заношу, сохранён в utf8, но на выходе всё равно имею такой результат[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этого не может быть. Пишите **полный** воспроизводимый пример. Код, который выводит строку на русском, потом создает таблицу в БД, записывает в нее эту строку, запрашивает обратно и выводит. Если этот код будет выводить вопросы - будем разбираться. Если не будет - значит в текущем варианте какое-то условие не выполнено.

Comment: @Ипатьев, попробовал как вы сказали, завёз тестовый скрипт на веб-сервер. Выполняется успешно, но вместо вопросов получается вот такая ерунда: Ð¢ÐµÑÑ‚Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ ÑÑ‚Ñ€Ð¾ÐºÐ°. Но при echo в самом скрипте выводится нормально. Так что можно сделать чтобы и в базе через pma тоже нормально читалось?

Comment: выставить все настройки так, как написано в коде. и показать уже здесь этот тестовый скрипт

Comment: Для того, чтобы таких проблем не было нужно: 1. кодировка веб-страницы должна быть utf-8. 2. серверные php скрипты должны быть в utf-8. 3. таблицы и столбцы базы данных должны быть в utf-8. 4. Соединение с базой данных должно быть в utf-8

Comment: @Yexeed  попробуй записать в базу вот так $text=mb_convert_encoding('тестовый текст', 'UTF-8');